# Deploy an AWS Application Load Balancer(ALB) in Front of AWS EC2 with MySQL (3306)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I know that if I use a AWS NLB in front of my EC2 with MySQL DB will work, but Im curious if will work too using an AWS ALB.

My Idea:

```
Internet <-> ALB <-> EC2 with MySQL
```

Is that possible or I need to use an NLB?

*Note: I know about RDS(Read Replicas) / AuroraDB(Global), but I have that question about ALB and MySQL*

Comment: NLB you mean Network Load Balancer? And of course you can Application Lad Balancer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, an Application Load Balancer only supports the HTTP and HTTPS protocols, so it will not be able to work with MySQL connections. See the comparison table of the different load balancer types [here](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/features/#compare).